# Inverting lower triangular matrix in time $n^2$

Tags: matrices, matrix-inverse

I have a lower $n\times n$ triangular matrix called $A$ and I want to get $A^{-1}$ solved in $O(n^2)$. How can I do it?

I tried using a method called "forward substitution", but the inversion is solved in $O(n^3)$ for full $n\times n$ matrix.

Comment: We can decompose the matrix $A\in M_{n\times n}$ into many fragments may be each fragment is in $M_{O(n^{\alpha}) \times O(n^{\alpha}) }$, $\alpha<1$ and $\alpha$ is choosed later, and then mutiplicate these fragments separately, and at the same time, we find that these multiplications are repeated to a certain extent, so as to get a better result than $O(n^3)$. In fact we can use the decomposite process at infinite scale, to gain a algorithm with time complexity $O(n^{3-O(\alpha)})$, but it is unknown if this argument can gain a algorithm with time complexity $O(n^{2+\epsilon})$

Answer (score 91, accepted):

No such method is known at present.

If one could invert lower triangular $n \times n$ matrices in time $O(n^2)$
then one could multiply $N \times N$ matrices in time $O(N^2)$.
Indeed let $n=3N$ and apply the putative inversion algorithm to
the block matrix
$$
\left( 
  \begin{array}{ccc} I & 0 & 0 \cr B & I & 0 \cr 0 & A & I \end{array} 
\right) 
$$
for any $N\times N$ matrices $A,B$: the inverse is
$$
\left( 
   \begin{array}{rrr} I & 0 & 0 \cr -B & I & 0 \cr AB & \!\!\! -A & I \end{array} 
\right) \, ,
$$
so you could read $AB$ off the bottom left block.

It is still an open problem whether general matrix multiplication
can be done in time $O(N^2)$, or even $O(N^{2+o(1)})$.  In particular
it follows that no method is known to do what you are asking.

In fact it is known that conversely an algorithm that takes
$O(N^2)$ or $O(N^{2+o(1)})$ time to multiply $N \times N$ matrices
would let us also invert $n \times n$ matrices in time
$O(n^2)$ or $O(n^{2+o(1)})$ respectively
(with a different $O$-constant, and not limited to triangular matrices).
So your question is in fact equivalent to the open question about
fast matrix multiplication.  See for instance page 3 of
[these
lecture notes](https://www.lehigh.edu/~gi02/m242/08linstras.pdf) by Garth Isaak, which also shows the block-diagonal trick
(in the upper- instead of lower-triangular setting).

**POSTSCRIPT** Strictly speaking, the reduction from
$O(N^c)$ matrix multiplication to $O(n^c)$ inversion of
triangular matrices means only that **either** we don't know how to attain
$c=2$ or $c=2+o(1)$ in the latter problem, **or** such an algorithm is known
but somehow nobody has noticed that this solves the former problem.
But the second possibility seem most unlikely, because fast matrix
multiplication is such a celebrated problem, and its reduction to
triangular-matrix inversion is quite well known.

Comment: The perfect answer !

Comment: this answer is really beautiful.

Comment: I think it _is_ known that we cannot have an algorithm with complexity $O(N^2)$ (though $O(N^{2+o(1)})$ is certainly unknown). Unfortunately I don't have a good source, only my [BSc thesis](https://www.universiteitleiden.nl/binaries/content/assets/science/mi/scripties/bachelor/2017-2018/smeding-bsc-scriptie.pdf) which (I think) shows in Theorem 2.6.2 that the rank of the <n,n,n> matrix multiplication tensor is $>n^2$, which together with some relations between computational complexity and the rank of that tensor, show that the complexity can't be strictly $O(N^2)$. But I'm hardly an expert!

Comment: Note: my comment above refers to algorithms using just a sequence of operations from {+, -, *, constant scaling}, but I believe that's a reasonable restriction. It is also the restricted language that the tensor-rank based matrix multiplication algorithms search in.

Comment: I'm just putting this out there... it's gonna turn out to be $O(n^2 \log^2 n)$. Analogous to integer multiplication, but in two dimensions blah blah Fourier transform somethety something.

Comment: @Mitch Isn't this only true for toeplitz matrices?

Comment: @ABIM Toeplitz Matrix Multiplication (and determinant  and system solving and LU decomp) [can be done in $O(n^2)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix). What I am saying is entirely speculative about general matrices. Also what I am saying is that _everyone_ says $O(n^2)$ or $O(n^{2+o(1)})$ when there is an infinity of possibilities between those two. And if there is an accessible algorithm it'll probably have a $\log$ in it like integer multiplication, purely out of blind analogy.

Comment: I belive Toeplitz matrices can be done in $O(n \log^2(n))$ time
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379580901615


But then, I see your point.  Just the rate looked oddly familiar ;)